# Opening current directory in Explorer

Tags: windows, command-line

You open cmd and type (for example) `cd C:\dragons`

How can you open C:\dragons in the file explorer? Yes, you can use `explorer C:\dragons`, but that is kinda lame. Let's say I'm in the folder `C:\dragons\Red\WhiteCrests\infants`, this way just isn't convenient.

Already tried `explorer dir` and `explorer path` (both of which opens My Documents for some reason), just `explorer` (opens the Libraries folder), `open` which is undefined, `explorer dirname` which gives me that dirname is undefined, and probably other stuff that I can't remember.

Thanks in advance.

...Shamelessly adding to the question with a thought I just had, how can you open a file (say C:\dragons\intro.txt) with a specified program? Like, instead of the default one (like Notepad), open it in Notepad++, without using Notepad++'s (if one exists) command line stuff. Something like:

```
cd C:\dragons
intro.txt --Notepad++
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`explorer .` will open an Explorer point to the current directory.

`notepad intro.txt` will open it in Notepad (gotta have it in `PATH`; Notepad you probably do already). Same thing goes for Notepad++, put it in `PATH` and (maybe rename it to something more pleasing) and use `Npp intro.txt`.

Comment: If Notepad++ is the default application to edit a text file with then it's sufficient to use `start` in both cases, even.

Answer (score 6):

```
explorer .
```

That answers your first question.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the shorter command

```
start .
```